# I cannot convert this instance in a dictionary

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I was writing this line:

```
var factory = new Dictionary<Types, Func<IProblemFactory<IProblem>>>();
        factory.Add(Types.Arithmetic, ()=> new ArithmeticProblemFactory()));

public interface IProblem { ... }
public interface IProblemFactory<T> where T : IProblem
{
    // Some stuff
}

public class Arithmetic<TResult> : IProblem
{ }
public class ArithmeticProblemFactory : IProblemFactory<Arithmetic<decimal>>
{ }
```

And it tells me this error:

Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'Exam.ArithmeticProblemFactory' to 'Exam.IProblemFactory'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Error   2   Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

What am I doing wrong people?

Comment: This is what I call a factory of problems :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your IProblemFactory **covariant** to support this scenario:

```
public interface IProblemFactory<out T> where T : IProblem
```

Basically, this means that T can be an IProblem or anything that implements it in cases like yours.

Here are a couple of articles about Covariance and Contravariance in C#:

- [Covariance and Contravariance FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx)
- [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot Alfonso. You've saved my life

Comment: I know that this question doesn't have sense on this matter but.. what OOP book would you recommend me?

Comment: You're welcome! In my opinion once you know the basics of OOP and some patterns, practice is the best way to master it. Here's a nice book with the basics of OOP, OOAD, UML and more: http://www.amazon.com/Applying-UML-Patterns-Introduction-Object-Oriented/dp/0131489062/ref=sr_1_6?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1314234982&sr=1-6